# How to resolve google page speed issues for wordpress website

Tags: performance

My current WordPress website has several issues in Google Page speed test

1. Defer unused CSS

   - I have already implemented CDN and used plugins like WP Rocket(One of the top plugin for WP website optimization)
2. Reduce server response times (TTFB)

   - I don't know if this is something related to WordPress, but is there anything which can be fixed for this one?
3. Eliminate render-blocking resources

   - This issues was caused by this only, in my Google page speed test.
     /recaptcha/api.js(www.google.com)
     What will be the possible solution for this?

Also, i would like to know the top list of things to be done for optimizing WordPress websites.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. This is something that you probably can't change if you didn't create the theme yourself. It means that CSS that you don't need on page load is loaded later.
2. This is determined by the speed of your server (the server itself and its internet connection). If you use a caching plugin (I don't know if WP Rocket does cache, otherwise I'd suggest *W3 Total Cache* or *WP SuperCache*), that will speed up your TTFB.
3. You can add the `defer` attribute to your script tag. If you can't, *W3 Total Cache* might do that for you - here's how:
   https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-fix-eliminate-render-blocking-javascript-and-css-in-above-the-fold-content-on-wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried W3 total cache, but it seems like WP rocket did more optimization then W3 total cache or Supercache. Is there any wordpress i can do which really can help me in defer css and in TTFB?

Comment: @John, that depends on the plugin configuration. There is no "magic" solution that just optimizes everything. And most caching plugins do not cache for known users (logged in users), so you need to check the TTFB performance in an incognito tab.
Defering css can only be made manually, because you need to manually determine what to load when.